# JREPL to match URL that contains keyword

Tags: regex, batch-file, windows-scripting, jrepl

I am trying to use JREPL.bat to match URLs containing a specific term in a txt file (and then write the result back to the file).

This is what I have so far, unfortunately it is not returning the expected result. The result is always NULL:

`JREPL.bat "href=""(\w[^""]+/pdf4v/\w[^""]+)" "" /match /f html.txt /o -`

The `html.txt` looks as follows (in reality the file is much more complex; additional content represented by [...]):

```
[...]

<ul>
<li><a href="#" id="fav" onclick="return favoritesadd(8094,'fav.png','removefav.png');"><img id="fav8094" src="fav.png" alt="" border="0" /> <span id="fav8094">ADD TO WISHLIST</span></a></li>
<li class="sixcol right"><a href="https://documents.domain.com/content/updates/year18/jv/folder01/pdf/pdf8094.zip?exp=1567791065&hsh=5a49e7d4828603beddbfb058a1535f5e&dl=att&filename=pdf-00008094-16.pdf" class="tcenter"><img src="pdf.png" class="icon" align="left" />16<br /><span class="small">download pdf</span></a></li>
<li class="sixcol"><a href="https://documents.domain.com/content/updates/year18/jv/folder01/pdf4v/pdf4v8094.zip?exp=1567791065&hsh=246a7702296f7db363ecaa1746a8815a&dl=att&filename=pdf-00008094-40.pdf" class="tcenter"><img src="pdf.png" class="icon"  align="left" />40<br /><span class="small">download pdf</span></a></li>
<div class="clear"></div>
<li><a href="/details.php?id=8094&num=1&ss=1" onclick="$.open();return false;"><img src="/images/details.png" class="center" />Details</a></li>
</ul>

[...]
```

The expected outcome is:

`https://documents.domain.com/content/updates/year18/jv/folder01/pdf4v/pdf4v8094.zip?exp=1567791065&hsh=246a7702296f7db363ecaa1746a8815a&dl=att&filename=pdf-00008094-40.pdf`

Can anyone help? I am not sure why this isn't working.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following single command line could be used in the batch file with following preconditions:

1. `jrepl.bat` must be in directory containing the batch file containing this line.
2. The file `html.txt` must be in current directory on execution of this batch file.
3. The file `html.txt` must not contain multiple URLs with `/pdf4v/` in one line.
4. The file `html.txt` contains `/pdf4v/` not outside a URL.

The batch file command line:

```
@%SystemRoot%\System32\findstr.exe /R "href=.*/pdf4v/" html.txt | call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "^.*href=\x22([^\x22]*?/pdf4v/[^\x22]*)\x22.*$" "$1" /O html.txt
```

**FINDSTR** supports regular expressions just very limited and outputs always the entire line containing a matched string. So the case sensitive regular expression search string `href=.*/pdf4v/` finds all lines containing `href=` and `/pdf4v/`.

Those lines are output by **FINDSTR** to handle **STDOUT** which is redirected by Windows command processor to handle **STDIN** of **JREPL.BAT**.

**JREPL.BAT** runs a much more powerful JScript regular expression replace to match everything on a line definitely containing `href=` and `/pdf4v/` with marking the URL containing `/pdf4v/` and replacing the line just by the marked URL.

The search expression `^.*href="([^"]*?/pdf4v/[^"]*)".*$` is written in batch file with `\x22` for each `"` as `cmd.exe` interprets a double quote as begin/end of an argument string.

There is an even better solution using **JREPL.BAT** option `/MATCH`:

```
@call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "[^\x22]*?/pdf4v/[^\x22]*" "" /MATCH /F html.txt /O -
```

The search expression `[^"]*?/pdf4v/[^"]*` matches simply all strings consisting of 0 or more characters not being a double quote or a newline character non-greedy and `/pdf4v/` and 0 or more characters not being a double quote or a newline character. That is very simple and can result in false positives, but works for provided example.

JScript regular expression engine supports unfortunately not look-behind or other enhanced features of modern regular expression engines to limit the search on `href` values. But some false positives can be avoided using:

```
@call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "[^\x22]*?/pdf4v/[^\x22]*" "" /INC "/href=\x22[^\x22]*?\/pdf4v\//" /MATCH /F html.txt /O -
```

Lines not containing `href="[^"]*?/pdf4v/` are filtered out by this include filter before applying the simple search expression. That is still not perfect, but perhaps good enough for this task.

Comment: ```@call "%~dp0jrepl.bat" "[^\x22]*?/pdf4v/[^\x22]*" "" /INC "/href=\x22[^\x22]*?\/pdf4v\//" /MATCH /F html.txt /O -``` works like a charm. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try Regex: `href="(\w[^"]+\/pdf4v\/\w[^"]+)`

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5k9MJM/1)

Comment: Not working with JREPL. Error: JScript runtime error in Search regular expression: Expecting']' in regular Expression. Maybe an issue with the JREPL syntax? Did you mean ```JREPL.bat "href=""(\w[^"]+\/pdf4v\/\w[^"]+)" "" /match /f html.txt /o -``` ?

Comment: Try `"href=""(\w[^""]+\/pdf4v\/\w[^""]+)"`

Comment: Not working - Returns an empty file ```html.txt``` - can't figure out how to apply this correct and working regex with ```JREPL.bat```